# In 2018 my parents filled for me as a dependent, in 2019 i filled for myself and received my refund, when do I get my stimulus check?

Tags: united-states, irs, stimulus

In 2018 my parents filled for me as a dependent, in 2019 i filled for myself and received my refund, when do I get my stimulus check ?

Comment: Did you have the refund direct deposited? Did you check the government website?

Comment: Yes I got DD and I just get a status unavailable message from the irs website

Comment: Whether you can be claimed as a dependent and whether you filed a tax return are independent things. You can be claimed (or able to be claimed) as a dependent and still file a tax return. What matters is whether you can be claimed as a dependent for 2019.